# Visual Basic PictureBox autoscroll offset get/set

Tags: visual-studio

I have been trying to find a way to get or set the scroll value of a PictureBox with the AutoScroll feature on, but am getting nowhere.

I will very much appreciate any help.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was wrong (besides nobody seemed to care) :

When a PictureBox is laid over a Panel, the values to query do not pertain to PictureBox, but to the panel it is laid over :
Panel.VerticalScroll.value and Panel.HorizontalScroll.Value.

Now, I did not get help, but this may be useful to other poor souls expecting an extended hand :(